# Calling an expect script inside ksh script just hang

Tags: shell, expect

I have an autoexpect generated expect script that I'm calling from inside a korn shell script. Here's the content of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
/usr/bin/expect /home/user1/script.exp
```

if I run the above command on the command line, it runs fine. But if I put it inside a shell script(so I can schedule it in cron later), it just hang and never return anything, log file only shows this:

```
spawn /bin/bash
```

Can anyone offer any suggestion?

Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 1  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                      ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
            sleep .1
            exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
expect -exact "]0;daily@tatooine:~\[daily@tatooine ~\]\$ "
send -- "su -"
expect -exact "su -[K"
send -- "\r"
```

.
.
.

Comment: What is in `script.exp`?

Comment: script.exp is an autoexpect generated script that look like this: #!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 1  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                          ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .1}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
                sleep .1
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
expect -exact "]0;daily@tatooine:~\[daily@tatooine ~\]\$ "
send -- "su -"
expect -exact "su -[K"
send -- "\r"
.
.
.

Comment: Uuurgh! Please click `edit` under your original question and paste code in there - it is unintelligible in the *comment* area!

Comment: Just put the code in like you said! I'm new to this site...

Comment: When bash, or any shell, runs, they either go interactive or not. When running without any tty, they run in non-interactive way. To force running in interactive use `-i` switch. And note that expect is meant for interactive script. If what you intend to run can be accomplished without expect, you should avoid expect.

Comment: Bottom line is, if you can't force a script to have an associated `tty`, `expect` will not be able to communicate with the spawned process.

Comment: personally i never use `autoexpect` to do serious things. i think it's more suitable for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug what happend by adding flag -d:

```
/usr/bin/expect -d /home/user1/script.exp
```